# How to remove all special characters and letters from column in DataFrame in Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, string, character, letter

I have DataFrame like below in Python Pandas ("col1" is data type string):

```
col1
-----
1234AABY332
857363opx00C*+
9994TyF@@@!
...
```

And I need to remove all special characters like: `["-", ",", ".", ":", "/", "@", "#", "&", "$", "%", "+", "*", "(", ")", "=", "!", "`", "~", "~`"]` and letters (both large and small) like for example: A, a, b, c and so one...

so as a result I need DataFrame like below:

```
col1
-----
1234332
85736300
9994
...
```

How can I do that in Python Pandas ?

Answer (score 4):

I might phrase your requirement as removing all non digit characters:

```py
df["col1"] = df["col1"].str.replace(r'\D+', '', regex=True)
```

Comment: I agree, sometimes it's easier to limit what you can than to filter what you can't. This is one of them!

Answer (score 3):

You can also use `findall` to extract digit only:

```
df['col1'] = df['col1'].str.findall(r'(\d)').str.join('')
print(df)

# Output
       col1
0   1234332
1  85736300
2      9994
```

You can append `.astype(int)` to convert digits to a number: